# RoomDatabase notifying Flow when object not in query changed

Tags: android, android-room, android-jetpack

I'm noticing that Room is notifying a flow subscribed to an element with id X of the changes to the element with id Y. I always thought and developed thinking that only the items in the query would notify changes. Was i always wrong? I found this behaviour in room 2.2.6 and also in the latest beta 2.3.0 so i can only imagine it is not a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The granularity of reactive updates in Room is **table, and joined tables**. So if you write into the table, then any query that observes that given table will be invalidated and refetched.

Answer (score 3):

You could use 'Flow#distinctUntilChanged()':

```
db.getElementById(x.id).distinctUntilChanged().collect {
    // do something
}
```

This is the recommended usage by the Google developer advocate Florina Muntenescu. You could read more here:
https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/room-flow-273acffe5b57

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense